# Running FFMPEG Command on Android

Tags: android

Here's a snippet of the code

```
 String[] ffmpegCommand = new String[5];
  ffmpegCommand[0] = "/mnt/sdcard/com.ffmpeg_test/ffmpeg";
  ffmpegCommand[1] = "-i";
  ffmpegCommand[2] = "concat:/mnt/sdcard/com.ffmpeg_test/VID_3_25_2013_12_22.mp4|/mnt/sdcard/com.ffmpeg_test/VID_3_25_2013_12_28.mp4";
  ffmpegCommand[3] = "copy";
  ffmpegCommand[4] = "/mnt/sdcard/com.ffmpeg_test/output.mp4";  

  try {
      Process ffmpegProcess = new ProcessBuilder(ffmpegCommand).redirectErrorStream(true).start();

      String line;
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ffmpegProcess.getInputStream()));
      Log.d(null, "*******Starting FFMPEG");

      while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){

          Log.d(null, "***"+line+"***"); 
      }
      Log.d(null,"****ending FFMPEG****");

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I don't what to make of the executable ffmpeg command. "/mnt/sdcard/com.ffmpeg_test/ffmpeg";
The ffmeg comes with the source code and built into a share library libffmpeg.so   But nowhere is the ffmpeg executable command file.   Any ideas?

Comment: if it's a shared library, then it has no executable

Comment: If you can compile the source, then it should be ARM compatible

Comment: @Axarydax Why is that?